# Using DOMElement.addEventListener within Vue component is capturing preceding event

Tags: vuejs2, addeventlistener

I have a `Vue` component which within its `created` lifecycle method adds an event listener to the document to capture any clicks that are outside of root `$el`. Let's call this `Popup`

When I click an element which summons and mounts the above `Popup`, the document click event is immediately captured.

Here is a jsfiddle with simplified code: https://jsfiddle.net/awei01/5vuqjcxd/

And, in contrast, here is a pure js version which correctly binds the click event: https://jsfiddle.net/awei01/qzqku0w9/

As a cross reference, here is the vue forums post: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/document-addeventlistener-captures-a-click-preceding-listeners-creation/11558

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to `Vue` core team member `LinusBorg`.

Need a `setTimeout`

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/document-addeventlistener-captures-a-click-preceding-listeners-creation/11558

Here is a working example with the `setTimeout` implemented: https://jsfiddle.net/awei01/ovr9sr6k/

Explanation in english:

1. Click event occurs and enters `capture` phase. `parent` Vue component handles this event.
2. `parent` component sets internal `$data` flag to show the `popup` module
3. `popup` module gets instantiated and mounted. In the `created` function, the `document.addEventListener` event gets attached.
4. The click event `capture` phase completes and starts bubbling up the DOM.
5. The click event is now captured by the `document` because of the event listener we've just added. It fires the callback and it looks like nothing has occurred.

Solution:

1. Click event occurs and enters `capture` phase. `parent` Vue component handles this event.
2. `parent` component sets internal `$data` flag to show the `popup` module
3. `popup` module gets instantiated and mounted. In the `created` function, attach the `document.addEventListener` in a `setTimeout` function so that it gets attached after the click event is fully complete.
4. The click event `capture` phase completes and starts bubbling up the DOM.
5. The `bubble` phase of the event completes
6. The callback within `setTimeout` now runs and document now listens to clicks
7. Any subsequent clicks that bubble up to `document` will be captured.

Comment: Could you add a more explicit explanation of how you'd use `setTimeout` to solve your issue?

Comment: @thanksd. 2 year lag in replying... it's in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awei01/ovr9sr6k/